# Handling error in node.js & express

Tags: node.js, express

I build a server with `node.js` and `Express`.

Everything works great, but in some cases the client sends invalid parameter, that I don't predict, and I don't handle with. The result of these requests that my server failed, and can't serve other requests.

For example, In one of my function. I have the next lines:

```
            app.post("/getFile", function (req,res){
            // some code...
              fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, byteRoRead, start, function(err, bytesRead, buffer){
                  buffer.pipe(res);
               }) 
             })
```

Because the client sent incorrect start param, my server failed with the next error:

```
fs.js:457
  binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, wrapper);
          ^
Error: Offset is out of bounds
```

So now I can fix it, but there is many other error that I can't predict, so I want to gives a client response of unexpected error, but I want that my server would still alive.

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error - `function req,res){`.

Comment: @Scimonster: I correct it - In my source code, the syntax is OK. I didn't copy it correctly. but the question is general.

Comment: @BenFortune: Thanks Ben, I already fix it. But my question was more general: How can I identify this unexpected error, and send appropriate response to the client. I don't want that my server will shut down every time the client send unexpected parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express has built in error handling as a middleware. See http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling for a more comprehensive guide but as an example:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});
```

This middleware would catch the error, log it to the console and return a 500 page to the user. This also will stop the server crashing. If you wanted to log the error, but still let the server crash add `throw err;` to the body of that function.

This is sometimes a good idea as you may not want the server to continue to serve requests if it is in some unexpected error state. Refer to http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/ as a good brief guide on the subject. Also, see http://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors for a more detailed discussion.